# check the condition and remove dynamic controls accordingly c#

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have a combobox which has values 4-9, and according to that value I want generate runtime labels and textboxes. When I click on 6 then the code can generate 6 labels and textboxes as required, but when I click on 5 again one label and textbox should disappear or if I click on 4 again 2 labels and textboxes should disappear....which is not happening. I have this code in c#. What changes should I make in this code? Is there any other way that I can do this code?

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (comboBox1.Text == "4")
   {
      checkBox1.Visible = true;
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      {
         addlabel(i);
      }

      for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 4; i1++)
      {
         addlabel1(i1);
      }

   }
   if (comboBox1.Text == "5")
   {
      checkBox1.Visible = true;
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      {
         addlabel(i);

      }

      for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 5; i1++)
      {
         addlabel1(i1);
      }

   }
   if (comboBox1.Text == "6")
   {
      checkBox1.Visible = true;
      for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
      {
         addlabel(i);

      }

      for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 6; i1++)
      {
         addlabel1(i1);
      }

   }
}
void addlabel(int i)
{

   int left = 70;
   int top = 100;
   int step_x = 80;
   int step_y = 30;

   new Label()
   {
      Name = $"label{i}",
      Text = "Enter Subject:",

      Location = new Point(left, top + step_y * i),
      Parent = this,
   };
   left += step_x;

   int left1 = 357;
   int top1 = 100;
   int step_x1 = 80;
   int step_y1 = 30;

   new Label()
   {
      Name = $"label{i}",
      Text = "Total Marks:",

      Location = new Point(left1, top1 + step_y1 * i),
      Parent = this,
   };


   left1 += step_x1;
}


void addlabel1(int i1)
{

   int left = 200;
   int top = 100;
   int step_x = 80;
   int step_y = 30;

   new TextBox()
   {
      Name = $"textbox{i1}",
      Text = "",
      Size = new Size(122, 20),
      Location = new Point(left, top + step_y * i1),
      Parent = this,
   };


   left += step_x;

   int left1 = 480;
   int top1 = 100;
   int step_x1 = 80;
   int step_y1 = 30;
   new TextBox()
   {
      Name = $"textbox{i1}",
      Text = "",
      Size = new Size(122, 20),
      Location = new Point(left1, top1 + step_y1 * i1),
      Parent = this,
   };

   left1 += step_x1;

}
```

Any Suggestions? Help me out.

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints and debugging your code? what do you think is the problem?

Comment: Also, while i'm critiquing, there is a lot of code here, which bits are'nt needed? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) . You have 2 methods called `addlabel` and `addlabel1`, that doesn't help anyone nor your self. Also you might as well read this [Navigating through Code with the Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will write a minimal code for this but right now I need help for this problem. Can you help me please.. And I think the problem is in addlabel function itself.... I guess I should give some condition to check whether the value of combobox is changed again... But I really dont know how should I put it together...

Comment: add them to a panel...so you can dispose of the panel so you can start fresh...just an idea

Comment: Also note, you can take that number from the comobox and convert it to an integer and use it as the max of your for loop so that you don't need to repeat the same code over and over. [DRY](https://dzone.com/articles/is-your-code-dry-or-wet)

Comment: "I will write a minimal code for this but right now I need help for this problem." The sooner you create the minimal code example, the sooner we'll be able to help you. Indeed, you may well find that in writing the minimal example, you'll find the problem yourself.

Comment: (Does the code you've provided even compile? You have a lot of places where you're calling a constructor but ignoring the result, e.g. `new TextBox() { ... };`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int prev = 0;
    private Point lblLocation = new Point(70, 100);
    private Point tbLocation = new Point(170, 100);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int cur = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
        int tmp = cur - prev;

        if (tmp > 0)
        {
            // add new controls
            for (int i = 1; i <= tmp; i++)
            {
                AddLabel(prev + i);
                AddTextBox(prev + i);
                lblLocation.Y += 30;
                tbLocation.Y += 30;
            }
            prev = cur;
        }
        else
        {
            // remove controls
            tmp = Math.Abs(tmp);
            for(int i= 0; i < tmp; i++)
            {
                RemoveControl($"lbl{prev}");
                RemoveControl($"tb{prev}");
                lblLocation.Y -= 30;
                tbLocation.Y -= 30;
                prev--;
            }
        }
    }

    private void AddLabel(int i)
    {
        new Label()
        {
            Name = $"lbl{i}",
            Text = $"lbl{i}",

            Location = lblLocation,
            Parent = this
        };
    }

    private void AddTextBox(int i)
    {
        new TextBox()
        {
            Name = $"tb{i}",
            Text = $"tb{i}",

            Location = tbLocation,
            Parent = this
        };
    }

    private void RemoveControl(string name)
    {
        foreach (Control item in Controls.OfType<Control>())
        {
            if (item.Name == name)
            {
                Controls.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lott... you saved my day!! :-D

Comment: Glad I help you.